# Proxy to get data from SharePoint REST APIs

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, reactjs

We have a `react` frontend application. The data source for this app is `SharePoint Online` list and libraries.

We found a [solution](https://www.kofrimpong.com/sharepoint-rest-api-proxy-for-local-front-end-development/) in node js that serves our purpose, to call REST APIs from react front-end. But we dont have expertise in the same and would like to do this in .net core or .net MVC.

Is there any ready to use available proxy service by SharePoint? If not what should be the ideal approach in case the frontend is outside of SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

If you're building your application in C# then [SharePoint's CSOM library](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code) is probably the easiest way of doing this.

You can also use the [Microsoft Graph API](https://docs.microsoft.com/graph/use-the-api) or [SharePoint REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom).